# free() crashes the program at the second call

Tags: c, crash

Sorry my English is not good. I'm new to c and I was trying to calculate the summation and multiplication of two numbers in base b that b can be 2 to 10.

when I use `free()` for _mult the program crashes but for _add it's ok. I'm confused why this is happening.

here is my code:

```
int * convert(long long int x, int base, int *arr)
// convert the number to base b and return the array with length 64
{
    int i = 63;
    while(x != 0)
    {
        arr[i] = x % base;
    
        x /= base;
        i--;
    }
    for(int j=i; j>=0; j--)     arr[j] = 0;
    return arr;
}

int * add(int *n, int *m, int base, int * arr)
// calculate the summation bit by bit.
{
    int carry = 0, sum;
    int v1, v2;
    for(int i=63; i>=0; i--)
    {
        v1 = n[i];
        v2 = m[i];
    
        sum = v1 + v2 + carry;
        carry = sum / base;
    
        arr[i] = sum % base;
     }

    return arr;
}

int * mult(int *n, int*m, int base, int * arr)
// calculate the multiplication bit by bit.
{   
    for(int i=0; i<64; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
    int ind_m = 64;
    int index = 64;
    while(ind_m != 0)
    {
        int ind_n = 64;
        int carry = 0;
        int ind_arr, res;
        ind_arr = index - 1 - (64 - ind_m);
        while(ind_n != 0)
        {   
            res = ( m[ind_m-1] * n[ind_n-1] ) + arr[ind_arr] + carry;
            carry = res / base;
        
            arr[ind_arr] = res % base;
    
            ind_arr--;
            ind_n--;
        }
        arr[ind_arr] += carry;
        ind_m--;
    }

    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int b;
    long long int x, y;
    scanf("%d%lld%lld", &b, &x, &y);

    int *n = malloc(sizeof(int)*(64));//64 bit for digits
    int *m = malloc(sizeof(int)*(64));

    for(int i=0; i<64; i++)     n[i] = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<64; i++)     m[i] = 0;

    n = convert(x, b, n);
    m = convert(y, b, m);
    
    int *_add = malloc(sizeof(int)*(64));
    _add = add(n, m, b, _add);
    free(_add);

    int *_mult = malloc(sizeof(int)*(64));
    _mult = mult(n, m, b, _mult);
    free(_mult);

    free(n);
    free(m);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is correct but when I use `free(_mult)` the program crashes but there is no problem with `free(_add)` .

Comment: Note that a product can be *twice the size* of the multipliers. You might be corrupting memory by exceeding the array bounds.

Comment: Why are you returning a value from add and mult?

Comment: @stark So that you can chain functions.

Comment: @klutt The returned value is one of the arguments, unchanged.

Comment: @stark `arr[i] = sum % base;` changes it

Comment: Amplifying WeatherVane's comment, try this: `int *_mult = malloc(sizeof(int)*(128));`

Comment: I tried `int *_mult = malloc(sizeof(int)*(128));` but program still crashes when it try `free(_mult)` .  `_add` and `_mult` have  the same type why it can't free `_mult`?

Comment: @klutt How does that change the pointer arr?

Comment: @stark It does not change the pointer, but it changes the value the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: @stark Example of chaining: `strcat(strcat(strcat(strcpy(buf, hello), " "), world), "\n");`

Comment: Works only for 1 argument. Now try `add(mult(a,mult(a,b,10,a),10,a), add(a,b,10,a))` Don't forget which order args are evaluated.